# Read bytes from file and store in array - C

Tags: c, file-io

I'm trying to read all bytes from a .raw file and store it in an array, using fread. This is my code:

```
//open up card file    
FILE* file = fopen("card.raw", "r");

if (file == NULL)
{
    printf("Unable to open/create file\n");
    return 1;
}

//size of file
fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
int size = ftell(file);
fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);

//buffer array
int buffer[size];

fread(&buffer, 512, size/512, file);

return(0);
```

I want to read 512 bytes at a time and everything in the file. Now my code gives me `Segmanetation Fault`, why is this? I guess it has to do with memeory leak or something similar but I can't figure it out. I also tried to change the mode of the file `file` to `w` but then all file contents disappear. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Were you able to determine if `size` got the correct value or not?

Comment: This code will not be reliable.  `size/512` will be `2` for a file of size 1250 bytes which means you won't read all of the data.  You're not checking the return value of `fread` for errors/short reads.

Comment: not sure, but I would suspect the array buffer size. At compile time how will it know the size unless it gets from the file? Maybe define buffer to be big enough, say 512 bytes and see if it works.

Comment: @GauravSinha I don't think setting size to 512 will work since the file is 14.3 MB big.

Comment: @SeanBright could That be the cause of the segmentation fault?

Comment: No, trying to create an array that is 14.3MB is probably blowing out the stack.  On my machine `ulimit -s` returns 8MB.

Comment: @alvits no difference

Comment: As @SeanBright said, you are blowing up the stack because the buffer is so huge. Try creating the buffer in the heap: int buffer = new int[size]; and remember to release the memory at the end :)

Comment: @alvits: And where, pray tell, is this pointer whose address is being computed?  It isn't `buffer` itself, as you attest.

Comment: @SeanBright: If that were the case, then wouldn't the segfault occur before `read` gets called?  If so (and OP would have to verify that, as it was never specified), I think we have a winner.

Comment: ok, maybe use gdb, do a backtrace, see the line no. where it crashes, see how big size is, how big buffer is etc.

Comment: a side note, specifying 512 as size in fread doesn't necessarily ensure that the OS will be actually reading in chunks of 512 bytes. but it does affect the return value of fread i.e. number of 512 byte chunks read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are a few issues with your code:

1. **`size` and `int buffer[size]`:** `size` is the number of bytes in the file, so creating an integer array of size `size` will actually use `size * 4` bytes.  You mention in the comments that your file is 14.3MB so the `buffer` array will be 57.2 MB.  If you actually want to read 4 byte integers, then you need to adjust the size of your `buffer` array accordingly (divide by 4 and account for remainder - more on this later).
2. **Stack size:** The stack is limited on most systems.  If you are writing/running this on Linux, try typing `ulimit -s` at the command line to see the maximum number of kilobytes on the stack.  On my machine this is 8 MB and trying to `fread` into a larger array causes a segfault.  If you want to read this entire file in to memory, you will need to use the heap (`malloc`/`free`).
3. **`size/512`:** Integer division throws away the remainder, so this calculation is wrong.
4. **Typos/Other:** You don't want to pass the address of `buffer` (you are using `&buffer`) you want to pass the address of the first element of `buffer` which conveniently can be done by just using `buffer` (or `&buffer[0]` but you rarely see this in reality).

Here is a "working" version of your program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BYTES_PER_READ 512

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   
    long size;
    size_t number_of_ints;
    size_t number_of_elements;
    size_t read;
    int *buffer;

    /* Open up card file */
    FILE *file = fopen("card.raw", "r");

    if (!file) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open/create file\n");
        return 1;
    }

    /* Size of file */
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    size = ftell(file);
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);

    /* 'size' is the number of bytes, not the number of ints,
       so we need to adjust accordingly */
    number_of_ints = (size % sizeof(int) ? 1 : 0) + (size / sizeof(int));

    /* We want to read 512 bytes at a time, and we need to know
       how many we need to read to consume the whole file
       (this is identical to the calculation above) */
    number_of_elements = (size % BYTES_PER_READ ? 1 : 0) +
        (size / BYTES_PER_READ);

    if (!(buffer = malloc(number_of_ints * sizeof(int)))) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate memory\n");
        return 1;
    }

    read = fread(buffer, BYTES_PER_READ, number_of_elements, file);

    printf("I read %zu elements of size %d bytes (total bytes read: %zu)\n",
        read, BYTES_PER_READ, read * BYTES_PER_READ);

    free(buffer);

    return 0;
}
```

If you could describe what your intend to do with the contents of the `buffer` array, someone could potentially tell you a better way to go about it (the way you are reading right now is a bit odd...)